# jquery datepicker returns null even if date in the textbox

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-datepicker

I created a search form that contains parameters and has a section for the result in a table format (id with a link to load it, initiator, status ...)
.
2 of those search parameters are of type datepicker "dateFrom and dateTo"

I also have a div section use to load a the details (which includes datepickers as well) of the clicked searched item in a dialog-box.

The search function works flawlesly until i open the page into the dialog box.
Then once the page is closed the datepicker doesn't work anymore.

Once the dialog box is closed, i can get the value stored in the textbox ( $("#eccSearchdateFrom").val() ) but if i try to get it formatted $("#eccSearchdateFrom").datepicker('getDate'); it returns null. even if i change their date using the calendar or manually inserting a new date in the textbox.

Anyone have any idea why this would happen.

It seems to me like the function datepicker was lost when closing the dialog box but i can't figure out why.

THanks for you help

Yan

Comment: Can you post your code or a JSFiddle? It's very difficult to fix the problem if we can't see what's causing it.

Comment: I will post something tonight. will be thought tho cause the webpage that is loading is generated automatically and is stored on server that is not acccessible outside our network.
Yan

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers?

Comment: I does it in chrome 38.0.2125.101 and firefox 22.0
We do not support IE (bug with jquery (uploading file) and IE)